# Convert a string in a few int between commas in python

Tags: python

I am getting a number from a csv file to a list and would like to compare these numbers to other numbers, how can I achieve this?

```
num = [2,32,31,23,12,32]

csvnumber= ['23,43,41,21,34']
```

How do I convert the csv number into ints to compare with my num list?

Comment: `list(ast.literal_eval(csvnumber[0]))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x= ['23,43,41,21,34']

t=list(map(int, x[0].split(',')))

print (t)
```

Assume your list has only one element as your example.Output:

```
>>> 
[23, 43, 41, 21, 34]
>>>
```

Then reach each element in the list `t` with a `for` loop and append them to your list `num`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and the [`int`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int) factory function:

```
[ int(i) for i in csvnumber[0].split(',') ]
```

#### Example

```
>>> csvnumber=['23,43,41,21,34']
>>> [ int(i) for i in csvnumber[0].split(',') ]
[23, 43, 41, 21, 34]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new list, split the current list at the commas, and append the items as integers like so:

```
new_csvnumber = []

for i in csvnumber[0].split(','):
    new_csvnumber.append(int(i))
```